# How can a google chrome extension (like Aviary) capture the screen (webpage)?

Tags: google-chrome, screen, capture

I wonder how does chrome extension (like Aviary) capture the screen (webpage). Is is done on server side?

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's not server-side. Each client may have a completely different render on their screen (size of the window, custom font size, etc.)!

Chrome extension API has a dedicated method to capture a page of a specified tab: `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`. Please read [the Chrome Extension doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab).